# Como agregar dos filas de dos diferentes tablas en sql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la imagen, tengo 4 tablas: `Issue`, `Location`, `Technician` y `Task`. Ya tengo creadas 3 tablas (`Issue`, `Location` y `Technician`), pero no se como crear la 4ta. tabla.

En la tabla de Task tengo que agregar `Task_Id` como my primary key y obtener los datos de `Description` y `Location` que ya están en otras tablas. No se como agregarlos a la tabla `Task` para que me los muestre de la siguiente manera

```
Task Id-----Description-----Location-------Date_Requested
```

y así sucesivamente.

Espero haberme dado a entender, muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara por favor lee [ask] y trata de proveer un ejemplo mínimo y verificable

Answer (score 0):

Parece que lo que pretendes en la tabla `Task` es manejar relaciones entre `Issue` y `Location`.

Tendrías que usar los IDs, que serian los que identifican cada registro como único en sus respectivas tablas.

Por tanto, la tabla `Task` quedaría así:

```
Task_Id
Description_Id
Location_Id
Date_Requested
```

Y la consulta para unir los datos sería algo así:

```
SELECT 
    t.Task_Id,
    d.Description,
    l.Location,
    t.Date_Requested 
FROM
    Task t
INNER JOIN 
    Descripción d ON t.Description_Id = d.Description_Id 
    Location l    ON t.Location_Id    = l.Location_Id;
```

La cosa es simple: si observas el `SELECT`, cada dato se extrae de su tabla original, y si observas el `JOIN`, se usan los IDs para unir las tablas.

**PD**

Quizá todavía falte definir restricciones de unicidad y/o de *integridad referencial* en la tabla `Task`.

Comment: No será que necesita más bien un par de FK?

Comment: @Alfabravo `Description_Id` y `Location_Id` son llaves foráneas (FK).

Answer (score 0):

Para crear la tabla `Task`  primero tendrías que ejecutar los siguientes comandos.

```
CREATE TABLE Task (
      Task_Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
      Description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      Location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      Date_Requested DATE NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (Task_Id),
      FOREIGN KEY (Location)
       REFERENCES Issue (Description_Id),
      FOREIGN KEY (Location)
       REFERENCES Location (Location_Id)
)
```

Tras esto tendrías que insertar los datos en la tabla. Esto se realiza con las sentencias `INSERT` o `INSERT INTO` y para actualizar valores tendrías que usar la sentencia `UPDATE`.

Te añado la documentación de [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) y [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) (documentación más sencilla para personas que se están iniciando en el SQL) de estas sentencias.

Notas:

- No has especificado el tipo de dato de cada columna, así que lo he supuesto.
- También he supuesto que la clave primaria es un autoincremental. En caso de que no lo sea debes eliminar el `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- No tenía claro tampoco los elementos que querías mostrar en  `Description` y `Location`. Así que he supuesto que son las claves primarías de las tablas `Issue` y `Location`.